# Extract value from a json string in a hive table

Tags: json, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have data as below

```
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|asset_id  |chg_log                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|4455628986|[{'oldValues': [], 'newValues': ['COMPO_MAIL'], 'fieldName': 'Communication Type', 'fieldType': 'TEXT', 'lookupInfo': {'fieldType': 'TEXT'}, 'additional': {'GROUP_QUALIFIER': [{'qualifiers': [{'lookupKey': 'Communication_Type', 'value': 'COMPO_MAIL'}]}]}}, {'oldValues': [], 'lookupInfo': {'isClientLevel': False, 'fieldType': 'DATE'}, 'fieldName': 'Delivery Due Date', 'fieldType': 'DATE', 'newValues': ['1601771520000']}, {'oldValues': [], 'lookupInfo': {'lookupType': 'CUST_ID', 'fieldType': 'CUST_ID'}, 'fieldName': 'Customer Id', 'fieldType': 'CUST_ID', 'newValues': ['10486']}, {'oldValues': [], 'lookupInfo': {'isClientLevel': False, 'fieldType': 'DROPDOWN'}, 'fieldName': 'Process_Status', 'fieldType': 'PICKLIST', 'newValues': ['Request Review']}]  |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

From the Json string of the column **chg_log** I'd like to extract the value of the fieldName - Process_Status and it's newValues as Request Review. Expected result as below.

```
+----------+---------------+
|asset_id  |Process_Status |
+----------+---------------+
|4455628986|Request Review |
+----------+---------------+
```

The json is not in the same order every time. Sometimes Process_Status comes first in the json string and then Communication Type and so on...
I tried using function json_extract but couldn't get it.
How can I achieve this in spark Sql or Pyspark or Hive. Can someone help me??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column `chg_log` seems to be a *stringified* Python dict rather than a valid JSON string.

In Pyspark, you can use UDF to transform the dict into json then convert it to an array of structs using `from_json` and finally filter the array to find the field `Process_Status`:

```py
import ast
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

dict_to_json = F.udf(lambda x: json.dumps(ast.literal_eval(x)))

df = df.withColumn("chg_log", dict_to_json(F.col("chg_log")))

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "chg_log",
    F.from_json("chg_log", F.schema_of_json(df.select("chg_log").head()[0]))
).withColumn(
    "chg_log",
    F.expr("filter(chg_log, x -> x.fieldName = 'Process_Status')")[0]
).select(
    F.col("asset_id"), F.col("chg_log.newValues").alias("Process_Status")
)

df1.show()
# +----------+----------------+
# |  asset_id|  Process_Status|
# +----------+----------------+
# |4455628986|[Request Review]|
# +----------+----------------+
```

---

Another way by doing the lookup directly in the UDF:

```py
parse_status = F.udf(
    lambda x: next(i["newValues"] for i in ast.literal_eval(x) if i["fieldName"] == "Process_Status"),
    ArrayType(StringType())
)

df1 = df.select(F.col("asset_id"), parse_status(F.col("chg_log")).alias("Process_Status"))
```

Comment: Hi @blackbishop Thank you for the response. 
I have several asset_id in my actual data and Im running into exception 
RuntimeError: ("Caught StopIteration thrown from user's code; failing the task", StopIteration())

What is the best way to handle runtime exception in the UDF you provided??

Comment: Hi @bunnylorr, which one is giving you this error, first or second approach? I suspect it's the second one, you can add a try/catch in the UDF (for the part `next(....)`) and return None if there is an exception.

Answer (score 1):

In Hive there is very limited support for JSON processing: get_json_object returns string even if it is JSON array or map, also [JSONPath filtering does not work](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-get_json_object). This is why you need to extract, split and explode and filter everything in the query.

For example this `get_json_object(chg_log,"$.[].fieldName")` returns:

```
["Communication Type","Delivery Due Date","Customer Id","Process_Status"]
```

Looks like array, but it is a STRING, you need to split it to get array.

Also your JSON is not valid one. Instead of single quotes it should be double-quotes and `False` shoud be lowercased: `"isClientLevel": false`, not `'isClientLevel': False`

Demo with your example (See comments in the code):

```sql
with mytable as(
 select 4455628986 asset_id , "[{'oldValues': [], 'newValues': ['COMPO_MAIL'], 'fieldName': 'Communication Type', 'fieldType': 'TEXT', 'lookupInfo': {'fieldType': 'TEXT'}, 'additional': {'GROUP_QUALIFIER': [{'qualifiers': [{'lookupKey': 'Communication_Type', 'value': 'COMPO_MAIL'}]}]}}, {'oldValues': [], 'lookupInfo': {'isClientLevel': False, 'fieldType': 'DATE'}, 'fieldName': 'Delivery Due Date', 'fieldType': 'DATE', 'newValues': ['1601771520000']}, {'oldValues': [], 'lookupInfo': {'lookupType': 'CUST_ID', 'fieldType': 'CUST_ID'}, 'fieldName': 'Customer Id', 'fieldType': 'CUST_ID', 'newValues': ['10486']}, {'oldValues': [], 'lookupInfo': {'isClientLevel': False, 'fieldType': 'DROPDOWN'}, 'fieldName': 'Process_Status', 'fieldType': 'PICKLIST', 'newValues': ['Request Review']}]" chg_log 
)

select s.asset_id, split(s.newValues,'","')[f.pos] as Process_Status
from
(
select asset_id, 
--extract array of fieldName and newValues 
--returned as string, not array
--this is why we need to split and explode it later
--remove [" and "]
regexp_replace(get_json_object(chg_log,"$.[].fieldName"),'^\\["|"\\]$','') fieldName,
regexp_replace(get_json_object(chg_log,"$.[].newValues"),'^\\["|"\\]$','') newValues
from
(
--Fix invalid JSON
--replace single-quotes with double-quotes, convert False to false, etc, add more fixes if necessary here
select asset_id, regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(chg_log, "'",'"'),'False','false'),'True','true') chg_log from mytable
)s 
)s lateral view outer posexplode(split(fieldName,'","'))f as pos, field_name
where f.field_name='Process_Status' --filter
```

Result:

```
asset_id    process_status
4455628986  Request Review
```